# How to add a new column to an existing csv file based on another column within the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
top2016 = mean2016.sort_values('Snow Mean', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='NAME', keep='first').head(3)
top2016.to_csv('top3.csv')

top2017 = mean2017.sort_values('Snow Mean', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='NAME', keep='first').head(3)
top2017.to_csv('top3.csv', mode='a', header=False)
```

This is my code right now and my csv looks like this
[image]

I want to add two new columns, one named 2016 and one named 2017. Then it should show the corresponding locations under the yrs. I have tried several ways like assign, insert, and with something like `top2016['2016']=top2016['NAME']` but none worked. What's the best way to do it? This is how I want my file to look [image]

Any help please!

Edit:[image]

This is a portion of my mean2016 data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could works:

```
top2016 = mean2016.sort_values('Snow Mean', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='NAME', keep='first').head(3)
top2016.loc[:, '2016'] = top2016['NAME']

top2017 = mean2017.sort_values('Snow Mean', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset='NAME', keep='first').head(3)
top2017.loc[:, '2017'] = top2017['NAME']

top3 = pd.concat([top2016, top2017]).reset_index(drop=True)
top3.to_csv('top3.csv')
```

Comment: I tried this but it gives me ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: top2016['2016'] = top2016['NAME'] gives me the error

Comment: I edited the code, but it shouldn't give you an error. If you give an error again could you post a print of you mean2016 data frame?

Comment: I got KeyError: '2016'. I uploaded a portion of mean2016

Comment: that makes no sense. the problem must be elsewhere in the code

Comment: Is there a workaround like adding a new column with my own values in the code?

Comment: Yes. 
`df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = 'new value'`

Comment: Your original code works, it was just that 2016 and 2017 was used somewhere else in the code. So all I had to do was change the column name to something else. Thanks for the help!